# Extract 10'000 images from Google Earth Engine

Tags: tensorflow, conv-neural-network, google-earth-engine

I want to obtain 10k images of 100x100x[nBands] pixels each from Earth Engine.

I made a *Region* from which I want to select images.

I plan on creating 10k random points in the *Region* and selecting the 100x100 pixels in the surrounding area for each point. Then I would be exporting each image individually using the *Export.image.toDrive* function.

The export format is in TFRecords, which holds for Tensor Flow Records, a special compressed data type.

I believe this method to be terrible. There might be a more appropriate way to extract datasets from Earth Engine. As of now, I can export the whole *Region* as one enormous image.

I plan on using the data to train a Convolutional Neural Network.

1. Is there a better approach within Earth Engine to extract 10k images?
2. If not, then on TensorFlow side, could we use the whole *Region* image with some sort of kernel to feed new random training samples to the algorithm?

Any help is welcome! Thank you in advance for your answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Export.image` supports exporting *regularly spaced, possibly overlapping* patches of an image. If you wanted to do that, you could do it with a single export. But in this case, where you want to export patches at each pre-defined point in a collection rather than regularly-spaced patches, you should use [`Export.table`, which also supports TFRecord export format](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/tfrecord#exporting-tables).

You'll have to explicitly construct the 100×100 patches using `neighborhoodToArray` on the images, then sample the images at your chosen points.

(Example code in Python on the assumption that you're working in Python.)

```
# Exactly 100x100 kernel
kernel = ee.Kernel.fixed(100, 100, [[1] * 100] * 100)

neighborhoodImage = myImageToBeSampled.neighborhoodToArray(kernel)
samples = neighborhoodImage.sampleRegions(collection=myTrainingRandomPoints)
Export.table.toDrive(
 collection=samples,
 fileFormat='TFRecord',
 selectors=[... training data band name and feature property names go here ...])
```

I'm not personally familiar with the full details of doing TensorFlow training, but I've had [this complete example recommended as a starting point](https://colab.sandbox.google.com/github/google/earthengine-api/blob/master/python/examples/ipynb/UNET_regression_demo.ipynb) (and I used it to write up the sketch above). Note that this example does multiple exports because it is sampling within multiple polygons, but if you have a single collection of labeled points then you can use just one export task for that, as I've sketched out above.

Comment: "Export.image supports exporting regularly spaced, possibly overlapping patches of an image. If you wanted to do that, you could do it with a single export. "

That would be better than my current plans! thanks!
Would you use the "dimensions" parameter? That's what I tried but it led nowhere...

Comment: @FlorianFasmeyer Take a look at the [Exporting images](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/tfrecord#exporting-images) section on the same documentation page, particularly the `patchDimensions` and `kernelSize` parameters, and the figure showing how patches overlap.